# how to using C++ library in Golang?

Tags: go

I google for a while, it seems to that the cgo is support C++ now.
but when I call C++ function like C in Golang, it failed.
so I wanna know how can let cgo know that the function I call is a C++ function, not C function?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You're going to have to write a wrapper in C around your C++ .. a "double jump" as it were..

Comment: Don't it have a way to call C++ function directly?

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 ways to do that currently:

1. use swig, the official example is in [$GOROOT/misc/swig/callback](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/misc/swig/callback).
2. Write hand-made wrapper like you'd do for any other language that doesn't support C++.